# The order of polynomial $f(x)$ is $7$. If $f(x)+1$ can be divided by $(x-1)^4$, and $f(x)-1$ can be divided by $(x+4)^4$, can we know what $f(x)$ is?

Tags: number-theory, polynomials

> The order of polynomial $f(x)$ is $7$. If $f(x)+1$ can be divided by $(x-1)^4$, and $f(x)-1$ can be divided by $(x+4)^4$, can we know what $f(x)$ is?

I tried to let $f(x)+1=h(x)\,(x-1)^4$, $f(x)-1=g(x)\,(x+4)^4$, and supposed $$f(x)＝a_0+a_1x+\ldots+a_7x^7\,,$$ $$h(x）=h_0+h_1x+h_2x^2+h_3x^3\,,$$ 
$$g(x）=g_0+g_1x+g_2x^2+g_3x^3\,,$$ and use the Leibniz formula to compute the derivative of all orders of $f(x)$, and I get eight equations about the coefficients of $f(x)$, $h(x)$, and $g(x)$.  It seems we can solve these equations to get $f(x)$, but this is too inconvenient. I want to ask if there is a better way to get $f(x)$.

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! By `order` of a polynomial,  you mean its `degree`?

Comment: yes, its degree.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: The spacing is atrocious.  At first I thought my browser went wrong.

Answer (score 5):

We have

(1)  $f(x)=(x-1)^4g(x)-1$ and

(2)  $f(x)=(x+4)^4h(x)+1$

with some polynomial $g,h$ of degree $3$.

If we differentiate the equation (1), we see that $f'$ has at $1$ a zero of order $3$.

If we differentiate the equation (2), we see that $f'$ has at $-4$ a zero of order $3$.

Thus

$f'(x)=a(x-1)^3(x+4)^3$.

Can you proceed ?